# Is there a way to perceive vibrations more effectively when device rings?

Tags: vibration

I have an HTC Desire HD. I work in a noisy environment as well as ride a motorbike. I often don't hear or feel the vibrations when the phone rings.  One of my previous phones had a function where it would ring once every 60 seconds until I attended to the message on my phone.

Is there a way that will provide this service?

Another issue is that sometimes the volume gets reduced. I must accidentally turn it off when I put the phone on my belt clip. One day I had 20 missed calls when checked because the device didn't ring for those calls.

Comment: IMHO the simplest solution would be using a Bluetooth headset. Right in the ear you should hear the ringtone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [MissedReminder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.murryelectronics.missedreminder). It's free.

> Hate missing txt messages?This will keep notifying of new unread text
>   messages
>
> Do you hate it when you are away from your phone or in a loud place
>   and miss a text message? This app will keep notifying you when you
>   have a new unread text message so you don't miss it. It is
>   customizable to notify as often or as long as you want. The default
>   settings will notify you every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Notification plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jmoyer.NotificationPlus).

It's made for phones that don't have a notification LED to inform the owner of pending (unnoticed) events. From the Play Store description:

> Notification Plus delivers recurring notifications via the phone's vibrator or notification ringtone. This is especially useful for phones which lack a notification LED, such as the Nexus S and Galaxy S variants.
>   Because there is no way for the application to receive all notifications in a uniform way, only certain events will trigger the recurring notification. Those events include:
>   - SMS messages
>   - GMail messages
>   - Missed calls
>   This application is free software, licensed under the GNU GPL v3. The source code can be found on the project home page:
>   http://code.google.com/p/notification-plus/